# Cordova Camera Sends Empty File To ASP.net Server

Tags: asp.net, cordova

I am trying to send a image taken from cordova camera to my server. The problem is that the server is returning me null for the image. I have tried to trustAllHost for cordovaCamera but to no avail, what could be the problem? Thanks!

Cordova Side:

```
.controller('MapCtrl',function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaGeolocation, StoreService, dataFactory){

$scope.getPhoto = function(){

    //--------------------- get geolocation lat long --------//
        var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
          $cordovaGeolocation
            .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
            .then(function (position) {
              var latitude  = position.coords.latitude
              var longitude = position.coords.longitude

              console.log("photo lat: "+latitude+" photo long: "+longitude);
            }, function(err) {
              // error
            });
    //--------------------- get geolocation lat long --------//

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        var options = {
          quality: 100,
          //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          //sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          //allowEdit: true,
          //encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 320,
          targetHeight: 320,
          //popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

          console.log(imageData);




        //----- get datetime----//
        var d = new Date();
        console.log("datetime: "+d);
        //----- get datetime----//


        //--------------------- upload image into server --------//

var server = 'http://192.168.2.50/webservice.asmx/SaveImage';
        var trustAllHosts = true;

        var ftOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
        ftOptions.fileKey = 'file';
        ftOptions.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        ftOptions.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
        ftOptions.httpMethod = 'POST';

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();


        fileTransfer.upload(imageData, encodeURI(server), win, fail, ftOptions);

        function win(r) {
            alert("Photo uploaded");
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log(error);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }
        //--------------------- upload image into server --------//

        }, function(err) {
          // error
          alert('Failed because: ' + err);
        });

    }, false);

}
})
```

Note: ImageData returns me valid URL (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ionicnavigationtest216511/cache/1442991645110.jpg)

> r.responseCode returns me 200(assumed to be http 200 OK status)
>
> r.response returns me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://www.xxx.<hidden>.<hidden>" />
```

> r.bytesent returns me 32880

WebService Portion:

```
  public string SaveImage()
    {
        
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"];

        if (file == null)
            return null;

     //   string targetFilePath = "c:\\deposit\\" + file.FileName;
       // file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
        return file.FileName.ToString();
    }
```

Note: When I test for (file == null) , it returns me true. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update 1: Changing the size of the image (lowering the quality to 10 and bytes sent to 112) did not solve the problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about asp, but I asume this code is for getting a file with recFile name

```
public string SaveImage()
    {

        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"];

        if (file == null)
            return null;

     //   string targetFilePath = "c:\\deposit\\" + file.FileName;
       // file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
        return file.FileName.ToString();
    }
```

but on the FileUploadOptions you are sending the fileKey as file

```
var ftOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
        ftOptions.fileKey = 'file';
        ftOptions.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        ftOptions.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
        ftOptions.httpMethod = 'POST';
```

So, change the `fileKey` to `recFile` or change the asp code go the "file"

Answer (score 0):

You should use camera plugin in this way, please read comments carefully.

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL //make it FILE_URI to get image as a file
    }); 

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var image = imageData; // base 64 encoded string, if type is FILE_URI then will contain iamge path on device

    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Also see the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: The image file can be sent , right now is the server cant get the file. And  I'm using ionic plus cordova.

Comment: If you set camera destination type as FILE_URI then, there might be problem with your upload code or image decoding at server site.....can't help any more as m not familiar with server side coding